# request.auth.uid always null in Cloud Firestore rules

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am implementing Firebase Security Rules, and I am having trouble with calls by authenticated users. I have written rules like:

```
    // Helper functions
    function isAuthenticated() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }
```

However, the isAuthenticated function never return true. Instead, when I set the request.auth == null this return true. In my example below, I have tested it for my jobs collection:

```
allow read: if request.auth == null;
// Returns true and jobs are accessible
```

Here is my client side code that logs the user in, and then makes a call to the db to set the user:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import firebaseApp from "@/utils/firebase";
import {
  getAuth,
  setPersistence,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  browserSessionPersistence,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import LoginWithSocial from "./LoginWithSocial";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { setLoggedInUser } from "@/features/user/userSlice";
import { getDocument } from "@/utils/helpers";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Input from "@/components/common/form/input";
import { EMAIL_REGEX, ERRORS, PASSWORD_REGEX } from "@/utils/common";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const FormContent = ({ onSuccess, handleSignup, handleForgetPassword }) => {
  const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [remember, setRemember] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const router = useRouter();
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    setLoading(true);
    //if user clicks on remember me
    if (remember) {
      try {
        setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence)
          .then(() => {
            signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, data?.email, data?.password)
              .then(async (res) => {
                if (res?.user?.uid) {
                  createUserEntity(res.user);
                }
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log("err", err);
                toast.error(ERRORS[err?.code]);
              })
              .finally(() => {
                setLoading(false);
              });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            // Handle Errors here.
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            console.error(errorCode, errorMessage);
          });
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle error here
        toast.error("Login failed. Please check your email and password.");
        setLoading(false);
        console.error(error);
      }
    } else {
      try {
        await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, data?.email, data?.password)
          .then(async (res) => {
            if (res?.user?.uid) {
              createUserEntity(res.user);
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("err", err);
            toast.error(ERRORS[err?.code]);
          })
          .finally(() => {
            setLoading(false);
          });
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle error here
        toast.error("Login failed. Please check your email and password.");
        setLoading(false);
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  };

  const createUserEntity = async (user) => {
    const userDocument = await getDocument("users", user.uid);

    if (userDocument?.data) {
      const userProfile = await getDocument(
        "profiles",
        userDocument?.data?.profileId
      );
      if (userProfile?.data) {
        if (!userProfile?.data?.emailVerified) {
          localStorage.setItem("emailForSignIn", userProfile?.data?.email);
          router.push("/verify-account");
        } else {
          dispatch(setLoggedInUser(userProfile?.data));
          onSuccess();
          setLoading(false);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="form-inner">
      <h3>Login to Minka</h3>

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <Input
            errors={errors}
            label="Email Address"
            name="email"
            register={register}
            placeholder="Email"
            rules={{
              required: { value: true, message: "This field is required" },
              pattern: {
                value: EMAIL_REGEX,
                message: "Please enter a valid email address",
              },
            }}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <Input
            errors={errors}
            label="Password"
            name="password"
            register={register}
            placeholder="Password"
            type={"password"}
            rules={{
              required: { value: true, message: "This field is required" },
              // pattern: {
              //   value: PASSWORD_REGEX,
              //   message:
              //     "Password must contain 6-20 characters (digit & uppercase & lowercase & special character)",
              // },
            }}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <div className="field-outer">
            <div className="input-group checkboxes square">
              <input
                onChange={(e) => setRemember(e.target.checked)}
                type="checkbox"
                name="remember-me"
                id="remember"
              />
              <label htmlFor="remember" className="remember">
                <span className="custom-checkbox"></span>
                Remember me
              </label>
            </div>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="call-modal reset-password"
              onClick={handleForgetPassword}
              style={{ display: "block", whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}
            >
              Forgot Password?
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <button
            className="theme-btn btn-style-one"
            type="submit"
            name="log-in"
          >
            {loading ? "loading..." : "Log In"}
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>

      <div className="bottom-box">
        <div className="text">
          Don&apos;t have an account?{" "}
          <button onClick={handleSignup} className="call-modal signup">
            Sign up
          </button>
        </div>

        {/* <div className="divider">
          <span>or</span>
        </div>
        <LoginWithSocial onSuccess={onSuccess} /> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormContent;
```

When signing in, my user welcome name and email is properly set. I am currently on:  "firebase": "^10.1.0",

Comment: The `getDocument` is not a standard Firestore API call and seems something custom for your app. The rules are also too short a snippet, as we can't see what collection they're applied to. Can you show how to [reproduce the problem with a minimal amount of code without any dependencies that we can't see](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?